# @carbon/react with Next.js 13 has anormal styles

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, carbon-design-system

I've created a Next.js application with:

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest
```

I've setup the package with:

```bash
npm i -S @carbon/react
```

I've modified `app/globals.scss` with this code:

```scss
@use '@carbon/react';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground: #000;
  --background-start: #222;
  --background-end: #000;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground: #000;
    --background-start: #222;
    --background-end: #000;
  }
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: var(--foreground);
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      var(--background-end)
    )
    var(--background-start);
}
```

I've this `Home` page:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth | null>(null);
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
      {auth == null ? <SigIn setAuth={setAuth}/> : null}
    </main>
  )
}
```

This is my `SigIn` component:

```
export default function SigIn({setAuth}: SigInProps) {
  return (
    <Form aria-label="Sig in">
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
        <TextInput required id="username" labelText="Username" inline maxLength={25}/>
        <TextInput required id="password" labelText="Password" inline type="password" maxLength={64}/>
        <Button>Sig in</Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

When I run `npm run dev`, I expected the input labels to be above the input boxes and the button to have a blue background. Other styles of the Carbon Design System look fine.

[Here's the IBM's storybook for `Button`.](https://v7-react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-button--default)

Here's what I get:

[image: Picture 1]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I just imported the `index.scss` file directly in root layout file and it worked. So you can just use the following line

```
import '@carbon/react/index.scss'
```

inside the `app/layout.tsx` file which will fix the issue. Hope it helps.